# Inverse of Cartan matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, root-systems

The Cartan matrix of the root system $A_n$ looks like, denote it by $A'_n$

$$A'_n= \begin{bmatrix}
       2 & -1 & 0 & 0&\ldots & 0          \\[0.3em]
       -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\[0.3em]
       0 &-1 &2  & -1 & \ldots & 0   \\[0.3em] 
      \vdots & & &\ddots & 2& -1  \\[0.3em]
0 & \ldots & & & -1&2
     \end{bmatrix}$$

I need to find the inverse matrix explicitly. I know that $det A'_n=n+1$, using this and the fact that $$b_{ij}:=(A'_n)_{ij}^{-1}=(-1)^{i+j}\frac{\text{det}(A''_n)_{ij}}{\text{det}(A'_n)_{ij}}$$(Where $(A''_n)_{ij}$ is the matrix $A'_n$ with i-th row and j-th column removed) For the first row I could find that $$ b_{1k} =  \frac{n-k+1}{n+1} $$
But this nice pattern does not continue for other rows....
Is there an easier way to approach this problem ? I would appreciate any hints/suggestions/answers for this problem.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if this would be helpful, for $A_{6}$ the inverse is the following:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \frac{6}{7} & \frac{5}{7} & \frac{4}{7} & \frac{3}{7} & \frac{2}{7} & \frac{1}{7} \\
 \frac{5}{7} & \frac{10}{7} & \frac{8}{7} & \frac{6}{7} & \frac{4}{7} & \frac{2}{7} \\
 \frac{4}{7} & \frac{8}{7} & \frac{12}{7} & \frac{9}{7} & \frac{6}{7} & \frac{3}{7} \\
 \frac{3}{7} & \frac{6}{7} & \frac{9}{7} & \frac{12}{7} & \frac{8}{7} & \frac{4}{7} \\
 \frac{2}{7} & \frac{4}{7} & \frac{6}{7} & \frac{8}{7} & \frac{10}{7} & \frac{5}{7} \\
 \frac{1}{7} & \frac{2}{7} & \frac{3}{7} & \frac{4}{7} & \frac{5}{7} & \frac{6}{7} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and for $A_{10}$ is the following:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 \frac{10}{11} & \frac{9}{11} & \frac{8}{11} & \frac{7}{11} & \frac{6}{11} & \frac{5}{11} & \frac{4}{11} & \frac{3}{11} & \frac{2}{11} & \frac{1}{11} \\
 \frac{9}{11} & \frac{18}{11} & \frac{16}{11} & \frac{14}{11} & \frac{12}{11} & \frac{10}{11} & \frac{8}{11} & \frac{6}{11} & \frac{4}{11} & \frac{2}{11} \\
 \frac{8}{11} & \frac{16}{11} & \frac{24}{11} & \frac{21}{11} & \frac{18}{11} & \frac{15}{11} & \frac{12}{11} & \frac{9}{11} & \frac{6}{11} & \frac{3}{11} \\
 \frac{7}{11} & \frac{14}{11} & \frac{21}{11} & \frac{28}{11} & \frac{24}{11} & \frac{20}{11} & \frac{16}{11} & \frac{12}{11} & \frac{8}{11} & \frac{4}{11} \\
 \frac{6}{11} & \frac{12}{11} & \frac{18}{11} & \frac{24}{11} & \frac{30}{11} & \frac{25}{11} & \frac{20}{11} & \frac{15}{11} & \frac{10}{11} & \frac{5}{11} \\
 \frac{5}{11} & \frac{10}{11} & \frac{15}{11} & \frac{20}{11} & \frac{25}{11} & \frac{30}{11} & \frac{24}{11} & \frac{18}{11} & \frac{12}{11} & \frac{6}{11} \\
 \frac{4}{11} & \frac{8}{11} & \frac{12}{11} & \frac{16}{11} & \frac{20}{11} & \frac{24}{11} & \frac{28}{11} & \frac{21}{11} & \frac{14}{11} & \frac{7}{11} \\
 \frac{3}{11} & \frac{6}{11} & \frac{9}{11} & \frac{12}{11} & \frac{15}{11} & \frac{18}{11} & \frac{21}{11} & \frac{24}{11} & \frac{16}{11} & \frac{8}{11} \\
 \frac{2}{11} & \frac{4}{11} & \frac{6}{11} & \frac{8}{11} & \frac{10}{11} & \frac{12}{11} & \frac{14}{11} & \frac{16}{11} & \frac{18}{11} & \frac{9}{11} \\
 \frac{1}{11} & \frac{2}{11} & \frac{3}{11} & \frac{4}{11} & \frac{5}{11} & \frac{6}{11} & \frac{7}{11} & \frac{8}{11} & \frac{9}{11} & \frac{10}{11} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I think the pattern is quite clear, but I do not know what is a good proof of it.

Answer (score 5):

The inverse of the Cartan matrix has the following formula:

$(A_n^{-1})_{ij}=\min\{i,j\}-\frac{ij}{n+1}$, for the inverse of other simple Lie algebra, there is a paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.01294.pdf

Answer (score 3):

With a couple of years of delay, I can answer you that on p. 95 of [Roselfeld's "Geometry of Lie groups"](https://books.google.de/books?id=mIjSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA373&dq=rosenfeld%20geometry%20lie%20groups&hl=it&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=rosenfeld%20geometry%20lie%20groups&f=false) there are the inverses of the Cartan matrices of simple complex Lie algebras.

EDIT: Up to transposition and without the typos in Rosenfeld, you can also find the same info on p. 295 of [Onishchik-Vinberg](https://books.google.de/books?id=TV7sCAAAQBAJ).